# Generating html image using JQuery when using rails helpers and embedded ruby

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I was previously doing the following in javascript:

```
    $('<img>')
        .attr('class', 'logo')
        .attr('src', '/images/logos/all/logo_one_beta.png')
        .appendTo('#container');
```

Now that I'm porting to rails I've been using embedded ruby in html and the image_tag rails helper such as

```
    <%= image_tag "logos/all/logo_one_beta.png", :class => "logo" %>
```

with logo_one_beta.png located at app/assets/images/logos/all/
The embedded ruby in html works fine but I want to add it to the html via javascript using the jquery appendTo method as I was previously doing.

I tried the following and it is not working:

```
    $('<%= image_tag "logos/all/logo_one_beta.png", :class => "logo" %>').appendTo('#container');
```

I also tried

```
    $("#container").append('<%= image_tag "logos/all/logo_one_beta.png", :class => "logo" %>')
```

I don't receive any error, the image simply doesn't show up.

Comment: Hey I doubt if you can render the HTML_helper for Ruby inside append, let me know if its true `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where's that code? on a .js file? or in a .js.erb view? you can't use ruby code inside a simple js file

use the debugger of your favourite browser to see what's happening there

I don't think you need to port that to rails anyway

Comment: That did it! I changed my .js file to a .js.erb extension and the images show up now.